# get node value by passing node name dynamically in Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, tibco

I am using Tibco xpath.

my inputs are like

```
<output>
<outputf1>123</outputf1>
<outputf2>123</outputf2>
<outputf3>123</outputf3>
<outputf4>123</outputf4>
</output>
```

Outputf1, outputf2 ..comes dynamically from another activity.

how to retrieve the value by passing the node name dynamically to the XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two XPath functions that provide the node name. `name()` provides the name including a namespace prefix, `local-name()`the name without it. You can select all element nodes and filter them by comparing the `local-name()`:

```
/outputs/*[local-name() = 'outputf2']
```

You can even combine that with `starts-with()` to select all "output" element nodes.

```
/outputs/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'output')]
```

Be careful with that - `outputs` starts with `output`, too.

HINT: This is really bad XML. If you can change it I suggest something like `<output index="f1">123</output>`

Comment: Question ..

Does local-nam() traverse through immediate child nodes alone ? How can i query a element by node name if it is like below
<outputFields>
<output>
<outputf1>123</outputf1>
<outputf2>123</outputf2>
<outputf3>123</outputf3>
<outputf4>123</outputf4>
</output></outputFields>

In the abpve case, i will only know outputfields ..so i can only map outputfields/*

So if i say outputfields/*[local-name()='outputf2']
will it work ?

Comment: local-name() does not traverse. It gets the local name of the current element. Traversing is done using the location path before the condition. `/outputs/*` are the child nodes, `/outputs//*` are all descendants.